# ¿por qué no logro realizar bien la comparación de calificaciones con el operador lógico | | utilizando el do... while?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, bucles, while

Comunidad ¡los saludo! tengo un problema al validar acá pues se supone que solo deben ser aprobados las calificaciones del 7 al 10, pero al introducir 11 por ejemplo, igual se da por aprobado. La idea es que no acepte ningún número por encima de 10 ni menos de 0 y que repruebe solo las notas de 0 a 6 y apruebe de 7 a 10. No sé si estaré utilizando el tipo de bucle incorrecto pues lo hice con do... while. Gracias de antemano.

```
do{
    var nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una nota"))
    if(nota < 0 || nota > 10 ) {
        alert("Por favor ingrese una nota de 1 a 10")
    
    } if(nota < 6 ) {
        console.log("Estas desaprobado")

    } else if(nota > 7 ) {
        console.log("Estas aprobado")
    }
    
}while(nota >= 0 && nota <=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu muestra está cerca pero le faltó detener toda la ejecución una vez que un valor inválido es ingresado y tomar el 7 como la mínima aprobatoria.

```
do {
    var nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una nota"))
    if (nota < 0 || nota > 10) {
        alert("Por favor ingrese una nota de 1 a 10")
    } else {
      if (nota < 7 ) {
        console.log("Estas desaprobado")
      } else {
        console.log("Estas aprobado")
      }
    }
    
} while(nota >= 0 && nota <=10)
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un `else` en el segundo `if`

```js
do{
    var nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una nota"))
    if(nota < 0 || nota > 10 ) {
        alert("Por favor ingrese una nota de 1 a 10")
    
    } 
    else if(nota < 6 ) {
        console.log("Estas desaprobado")

    } else if(nota > 7 ) { // aquí faltaba un else
        console.log("Estas aprobado")
    }
    
}while(nota >= 0 && nota <=10)
```